# Examples of Phonological Variation / Morphological Structure Interacton

Tags: cross-linguistic, examples, variation

English coronal stop deletion, or TD-Deletion, is a variable process whereby word final /t/ and /d/ in clusters are deleted.

```
soft -> sof
```

A phonological rule for TD-Deletion could be given as:

```
{t,d} -> 0/ C__#
```

It can apply in a variety of morphological conditions.

**Monomorphemes:**

```
soft -> sof
```

**Regular Verbal Morphology:**

```
missed -> miss
```

**Irregular Verbal Morphology:**

```
kept -> kep
```

What I'm wondering is if there is any other good examples of a process like this in other languages.  Here are my criteria.

1. The process is easily describable, phonologically.
2. The process applies variably.
3. The process applies in a few different
   morphological contexts.
4. Ideally, the process applies to a few
   different morphological exponents.

It would also be nice to know if the rate of variation is affected by the morphological structure it applies in/to.

Comment: I don't understand under which conditions the TD-deletion is done.

Comment: @thei, does my edit clarify?

Comment: Maybe you could give one example?

Comment: There are 3 examples in the question:

Comment: I mean: *When* is the t of soft deleted? (And yes, I realize that it is deleted in clusters, I just don't know what constitutes a cluster.) I am not asking these questions to annoy you, I am quite interested and slightly ignorant on the subtler points of English pronunciation.

Comment: It's completely variable, so sometimes it deletes and sometimes it doesn't. Some factors, including the following word, can affect the *probability* of deletion, but there's nothing that absolutely determines when it will happen.

Comment: People are not hidden Markov models - they don't mentally roll a dice to determine which of multiple forms they'll produce. You simply don't have enough data to determine the right conditions for deletion.

Comment: @AlekStorm: But it is possible that these conditions should fall outside the scope of phonology, isn't it?

Comment: @thei: Examples that work for me are /pæsbaɪ/ for "passed by" and /wɛsːaɪd/ for "west side".

Comment: @Cerberus: I assume you're referring to sociological effects like discourse context and setting, which can cause speakers to modify their speech to fit a "higher" register. However, when controlled for these effects, t-deletion should still not vary probabilistically.

Comment: @AlekStorm, there **is** such a thing as a variable process, and TD Deletion is one of them. To say there isn't is ignoring all of the sociolinguistic literature beginning with Weinreich, Labov & Herzog 1968.  Variation has been found in all levels of grammar, from phonology, morphology, and syntax (kroch, 1989).

Comment: Is it important that it is in other languages than English?

Comment: I think these separate questions should be asked separately.

Comment: @JoFrhwld, I'll concede that I am not a sociolinguist, and do not have immediate access to that work. Does it show specifically that *within a speaker*, when constrained to one social context, processes such as T-deletion vary probabilistically?

Comment: @AlekStorm, within a speaker, within a social context (stylistic, etc.), within the same preceding and following segmental context, the deletion of /t/ and /d/ is describable only probabilistically.

Answer (score 3):

Would Spanish /s/ deletion fit?  It applies in these morphological contexts:

- Stems ending in /s/
- The plural ending for nouns /-s/
- The verbal conjugations for second person singular /-Vs/ and first person plural /-Vmos/
- To the irregular 3rd sg. present tense verb form *es* (from *ser*).  It also applies to the 2nd singular and 1st plural forms of this verb *eres* and *somos* respectively.  (Whether these are represented as irregular root + usual affix or just an irregular stem is probably a matter of discussion.)
- In some dialects, the 2nd sg. preterite marker /-Vste/ has a non-standard variant /-Vstes/ (by analogy with the other tenses).  Insofar as this variant is produced, /s/ deletion can apply to it.  (It would be tricksy to measure this, though, as after total /s/ deletion this variant is homophonous with the standard form.  But you could count lenited tokens.)

Answer (score 1):

I have three possible examples that might fit your criteria, two from English and one from French:

- word final 's[unvoiced stop]' when followed by they noun plural morpheme or the verb singular morpheme 's':

> -sps, -sts, -sks  -> -ss  ( long 's'?)

As in 'wasps' -> 'wass' or 'basks' -> 'bass'

More careful or slower pronunciation will pronounce all three phonemes, but usual conversation uses the rule.

- '-ty-' -> '-tʃ-' (palatal glide to palatal affricate)

As in 'Don't you ...' -> 'Dontcha ...'. This seems to have no restriction in English to particular morphology (I've heard 'Rightcheer' for 'Right here').

- In French, it is common to drop word final syllabic liquids:

> 'table' -> 'tab', 'autre' -> 'aut'

I can't think of any morphological interacting instances.